# Show object property based on another object property in TableColumn (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Website object with a couple of properties:

```
private final StringProperty website;
private final BooleanProperty hasAccount;
private final BooleanProperty keep;
private final BooleanProperty delete;
```

and a TableColumn:

```
private TableColumn<Website, String> keepColumn;
```

Basically I want to display the `website` string in `keepColumn` only if the `delete` property is true, else don't show anything at all (not even an empty cell).

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to remove the complete row or a single cell in a row (which I'm afraid would be impossible (unless you simply want to move other column contents left, wich isn't simple either...))?

Comment: I'd like to remove the complete row

Comment: Yes i do. I figured out a way to do it seems like by using `FilteredList`. But I have 2 columns actually, `keepColumn` and `deleteColumn`. Object is in either one or the other. Does that mean I have to keep 2 seperate `ObservableList`?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the `ObservableList` for the `TableView` to only include websites with the true `delete` value?

Comment: I recommend providing a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do. It's not easy to guess without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ObservableList<Website> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        //your data
).filtered(i -> delete.get());
```